# How to prevent Slick slider from pausing when taping on devices?

Tags: jquery, slider, tap, pause, mobile-devices

I have a page with a slider (I'm using Slick). On a mobile devices when I swipe and tap in the same time with another finger on it - the slide freezes until I swipe again. I've tried the predefined options: pauseOnHover and pauseOnFocus but nothing changed. Is there any way to prevent this to happen? My code:

```
//slider
    $('.slider-intro .slider-slides').slick({
        prevArrow: ".slider-intro .slider-prev",
        nextArrow: ".slider-intro .slider-next",
        pauseOnFocus: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        mobileFirst: true
    });
```

Comment: have you tried the method slickPause? http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: This method is used when you have autoplay set to true. My slider has `autoplay: false;` Anyway, I figured it out - I used `touchMove: false;` and `touchThreshold` option to prevent direct sliding. It disables the touch event but keeps the sliding. So you can't exactly move the slide by click/tap and hold with the mouse/finger, but you still trigger the slide animation/transition to the next slide.